# How to add text file in my project so that it is not visible to user..?

Tags: c#

Sir,

I am developing an application in which i am to save some information in text file. During execution, I wish to read/write data from/to the file(.txt file). I dont want the file to be visible to user. Or if it is visible then it must be in programfile folder of the system and user could not delete the data of the file. What should i do? I tried to add the file in Resource file but could not read and write the file. PLease help me to read/write OR provide some other way to implement the same(described above).

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `ProgramFiles` (installation) folder:
1. File will be visible for user
2. If user won't have admin rights your app will fail on modifying the file.
`Windows System folder` is also question of rights. I'd advice to use system registry or appdata folder: you can get it `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`. You'll be able to write to that location without admin rights. You should create some special subfolder there (not needed, but would be convinient).
Or in registry case:
writing to registry:

```
string myEncrStringToSave;    
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Your_Cpecial_Key");
key.SetValue("Software\\Your_Cpecial_Key", myEncrStringToSave);
key.Close();
```

---

reading from registry:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Your_Cpecial_Key");
object value = key.GetValue("Software\\Your_Cpecial_Key");
if (value!=null)
   string myEncryptedString = value.ToString();
key.Close();
```

Your_Cpecial_Key here is some identifier (like in hashtable) that allows you to get access to your data.

Comment: Sir, I am very Sorry. I am recently passed graduate(2010) and is not too effecient in programming. I couldnt understand the above written code.

Comment: What don't you understand exactly? I've added some details for you.

Comment: Then don't forget to vote for my answer and mark it as correct :).

Answer (score 1):

you could use IsolatedStorage, it's not fully hidden but at least not easily discoverable as well.

Comment: ok, What if I wish the text file to be saved in installation directory and user could not modify it?

Comment: do you want the file to be readable but not editable by users or encrypted? if you want it to be readable by users, so a plain text file, even if you set as read only, hidden, and play with file system security, users will still be able to change those attributes and override the security, if they are admins.

Comment: I wrote encrypted strings in the text file. I dont wish these strings to be deleted by the user. And also I want to write strings in the file when user is using the application. As far as security overriding is concerned, data in file is not credential. BUt it is essential for application to be interactive.

Comment: Use registry as I described in my response. You'll be able to write there any amount of data. Or again, appdata folder.

Answer (score 0):

Put the file in the Windows System folder and use it from there.

You can access it without giving full path by using `Environment.SpecialFolder.System`.

This way user will have to work hard in order to find the file, but in case he does find you can't really prevent him from changing it as it's the same user running your program.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this might help you.
You may make the text file as an Embedded resource and get the same via

```
Assembly assm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
StreamReader aread = new StreamReader(assm.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.TextFile1.txt"));
```

So this is not accessible to the user nor available in the deployed location